# expression can be simplified on boolean literal

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, boolean, pycharm

I have the following code that reproduces a `PyCharm` warning,

> Expression can be simplified
>
> This expression detects equality comparison with a boolean literal.

```
seq_group = []
if seq_group == []: # warning here
   print("it is empty.")
```

if I change the code to,

```
if seq_group is None:
```

will fix the warning, but the real question is are `None` and `[]`emplty list the same thing?

cheers

Comment: I'd agree @ŁukaszRogalski and I'm sure the top answer fixes the warning. I'm a bit hesitant to close though since the actual question is if `None` is the same thing as `[]`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> are `None` and `[]` empty list the same thing?

Nope, and it will result in erroneous behavior:

```
seq_group = []

if seq_group is None:
    print("it is empty")
```

This doesn't print anything, `None` is completely different to `[]`, value and identity wise. `None` indicates the absence of a value, `[]` indicates a list with no values. The confusion might arise from the fact that both happen to evaluate `False` in conditionals.

The warning is probably due to the fact that you can simply use `seq_group` with `not` instead of using a literal with `==`:

```
if not seq_group:
    print("it is empty")
```

Comment: I also found that if `seq_group = None

if not seq_group:
    print("it is none")`, `it is none` will be printed., which means `not` also works when some object is `None`.